# Spinner and text field has become less visible due to background image

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

Due to the background image in relative layout, spinner and `TextField` have become dim or less visible. How can I make it more visible along with the Background Image. Here is the code :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/android_robot"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText> 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1" </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:entries="@array/Grades"
        android:prompt="@string/title" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change background color accordingly

Comment: i suggest make your background a bit opaque

Comment: Don't you need to define the `Spinner` before the `EditText` so the `@+id`, which btw says I want to create an id, you give the `Spinner` will be available to the `EditText`, which should reference it w/o the `+`?

Answer (score 0):

You can put thin `border` around them which will make them more visible.
You can add border by creating `drawable` something like this :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#439CC8" android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Change the values according to your need.

Comment: I want that let suppose if the background is of green color, than whole the spinner box must be of white or some other color so that easily be recognized. But, in my case, if I changes the background the whole spinner box acquires the same color as that of the background. I want to give whole spinner box a separate color than the background. How can i do so ???

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to my own Question. For Spinner and TextField in XML file just write
android:background="@android:color/white"  . It will be okay and will show Spinner dialog in white color, more visible to eyes along with the background.